# message when responses are made to questions you have upvoted

Tags: feature-request

If I have upvoted a question, I would appreciate notification (for example, in the message window under the StackExchange upper left) when there is a post or comment to that question.  Do others feel that way?

Comment: To add on Zev's answer, SE is a platform which encourages voting very often (note for the badges given for using all your voting in a single day, as well for voting competing answers and on many questions). This makes your request - while reasonable - impractical. A slight modification which is in order for your request is to replace the word "upvoted" with "favored".

Answer (score 13):

Personally, I think that there are far too many questions I've upvoted for notifications of activity on all of them to be practical to keep track of - I'd be swamped! Besides, the current setup of getting notifications of activity on precisely those questions which one has favorited is strictly better because it gives one the *ability* to disconnect "I want to get notifications of activity on this question" and "I want to vote on this question" (and these notifications are somewhat "quieter", because they are not in one's inbox, but only in the favorites tab of one's profile).

Comment: I never used the favorite question feature. What kind of activity triggers a notification? Comments to the question and newly posted answers, I presume, right? Is there a detailed description of that somewhere, I couldn't locate it on meta.SO (I admittedly didn't try very hard, though)?

Comment: I'm having trouble getting a clear description too. I found [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45360/subscribing-to-questions-and-comments-that-dont-belong-to-you/52093#52093), and my understanding of it is that edits or new answers light up the "activity on a favorited question" indicator, but comments do not. This matches my personal experience: even with [all of my favorites](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/264/zev-chonoles?tab=favorites), my activity indicator only goes off once in a while, while I would guess that comments occur on them occur more frequently than that.