# How can I send a message to all users who have marked a question as their favorite?

Tags: support, bookmarks, private-messages

How can I send a message to all users who have marked a specific question as their favorite?

Apparently they are not automatically informed when finally, after years of waiting, the question has been adequately answered.

Comment: You can't. This is not Facebook. People get very passive notifications to their profile which they may or may not notice in due time. And that's all you can probably do.

Comment: You could always try hiring a private detective.

Comment: Well, receiving a message that there is a new answer sounds pretty passive to me, as it can be discarded when it is not interesting. I am surprised that this is not standard practice - and no I don't need to know who's who, I just wonder why they are not notified automatically.

Comment: Yes, this indeed seems desirable.

Comment: IMHO favorite questions would be much more useful if you got notifications for all comments and new answers, similar to your own posts. As it stands, my relationship with the favorite question button is mostly to lie to myself that I'll read it someday so that I can close the tab.

Comment: At the moment, the favourite questions tab shows a really pointless notification, namely the number of new favourites there are! You go and look, and lo and behold, they're exactly the ones that you favourited! It would make far more sense if it instead showed how many had new activity, with those then highlighted in the list.

Comment: @timtfj I didn't check recently, but if that is the case, then the behavior changed. Because it used to display the number of favorites with new activity (being favorited unfortunately counting as activity).

Comment: Yes, the favorites tab does this for you. It is not always intuitive, but the favorite questions with recent activity can be found there. While we are at it, a feature I would like to have is notifications about new answers to those questions I already upvoted  on (either the question or an answer). This would give the later answers a fair chance to catch up: *You recently upvoted an answer to question [link inserted]. One or more new answers to that question have been posted. We would like you to help evaluating the new answers as well.*

Comment: But, given the large number of votes we have the right to cast, such notifications might clutter the system unbearably.

Comment: There were several feature requests and discussions about possibility of getting notifications for questions by others. On this meta: [Mark problems as “notify me if answer is posted”?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4867) or [A way to “watch” questions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6994) On Meta Stack Exchange: [Adding Favorites to the Stack Exchange global inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83343)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, the point that there would be too many notifications *for upvoted posts* was raised also here: [message when responses are made to questions you have upvoted](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2737). (This is slightly different from what you've mentioned - it is about upvoted questions.)

Comment: People who want to receive future notifications about a particular question, can click the "question feed" at the bottom right.  But that is not what "favorite" does.

Comment: @GEdgar Where's that button? I cannot find it on my MSE GUI

Comment: @Maestro13: On a question page in math.se ... right-hand sidebar ... below `HOT META POSTS` ... below `Related` ... below `Hot Network Questions` ... there is `question feed`.